# Generalization in SQL

Tags: sql, database

First of all, I have these tables:

1. `Users` table, containing userid and name
2. `Customer` table, containing just userid
3. `Seller` table, containing just userid
4. `Transaction` table, containing id of the customer, id of the seller, and the date.

I need to select all transactions and print their date, the name of the customer, the name of the seller.

```
SELECT user.name AS c_name, user.name AS s_name
```

I tried this, but having duplicates causing errors in my code.

I am able to extract their ids by

```
SELECT customer.id,seller.id
FROM customers, seller, transactions
WHERE transactions.c_id = customer.id 
  AND transactions.s_id = seller.id
```

But I just can't figure out how to extract the names. Maybe I am going in a completely wrong direction. Any help is appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: please only tag the database system you are using.

Comment: `customer` and `seller` are two independent columns. Hence you need 2 independent `users` table copies for to select according names.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You need to join also the users table twice for every seller and customer

Using the JOIN clause and alias  helps to make the querys more readable

```
SELECT 
    u1.name as c_name, u2.name as s_name
FROM transactions t JOIN 
customers c ON t.c_id = c.id 
JOIN seller s ON t.s_id = s.id
JOIN Users u1  ON u1.userid = c.userid
JOIN Users u2 ON u1.userid = s.userid
```